# How to position a row or column against another component, while keeping alignment with Elm`s mdgriffith/style-elements

Tags: elm, elm-style-elements

#### Context

I use [Elm](http://elm-lang.org/) with [mdgriffith/style-elements](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/style-elements/4.2.1) `v4.2.1` to create layout and style for a webpage.

#### Goal

I tried to position one right aligned row under another row.

#### Approach

The `Element` module of `style-elements` exposes a [below](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/style-elements/4.2.1/Element#below) function which should make this task simple.

Its type annotation with explanation as comments:

```
below
    :  List (Element style variation msg) -- List of components what you want position below the pivot element
    -> Element style variation msg -- pivot component
    -> Element style variation msg -- Returned component
```

A self contained example:

[interactive version](https://ellie-app.com/9xnYMh5Kha1/3)

`Main.elm`

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Color exposing (rgb)
import Element exposing (..)
import Element.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html exposing (Html)
import Style exposing (..)
import Style.Border as Border
import Style.Color as Color
import Style.Font as Font


type Styles
    = None
    | Title
    | Menu


stylesheet =
    Style.styleSheet
        [ style None []
        , style Title
            [ Color.background (rgb 0 0 0)
            , Color.text <| rgb 255 255 255
            ]
        , style Menu
            [ Border.all 3
            , Color.background <| rgb 255 255 255
            , Color.border <| rgb 0 0 0
            , Color.text <| rgb 0 0 0
            ]
        ]


main : Html msg
main =
    layout stylesheet <|
        column None [] <|
            [ row
                Title
                [ center
                , verticalCenter
                , padding 30
                ]
                [ text "Title" ]
                |> below
                    [ row Menu
                        [ alignRight
                        , moveUp 15
                        , spacing 20
                        ]
                        [ el None [] (text "menu 1")
                        , el None [] (text "menu 2")
                        ]
                    ]
            , row None
                [ spread, padding 50 ]
                [ el None [] (text "info 1")
                , el None [] (text "info 2")
                ]
            ]
```

`index.html:`

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    /* you can style your program here */
  </style>
</head>
<body style="position:relative">
  <script>
    var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen()
    // you can use ports and stuff here
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Result:

The positioned row went under the position pivot, but it is still left aligned.

[image]

The *menu 1* and *menu 2* items should be at the right

#### No workarounds please

It is possible to workaround this problem simply by using [moveRight](https://ellie-app.com/9xnYMh5Kha1/4) or the [paddingLeft](https://ellie-app.com/9xnYMh5Kha1/5) functions, but they are dirty fixes and prone to error, and according to this [lecture](https://youtu.be/NYb2GDWMIm0?t=769) positioning should work alongside alignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I peaked into the source code of `mdgriffith/style-elements` `v4.2.1` and found a positioning example in the tests.

`tests/Visual/Master.elm`, [line 302](https://github.com/mdgriffith/style-elements/blob/92789fd003c799c6f988202d6a4b7fe6e41194fe/tests/Visual/Master.elm#L302),

It passes the return values of multiple [el](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/style-elements/4.2.1/Element#el) calls to the positioning functions in lists, and apply alignment in them.

So I tried the same by using a list with one `el` function call as the first argument of the positioning function, and passed the return value of the `row` call as its third argument.

#### At this [link](https://ellie-app.com/9xnYMh5Kha1/6) there is an interactive example.

Here is the relevant snippet:

```
    [ row
        Title
        [ center
        , verticalCenter
        , padding 30
        ]
        [ text "Title" ]
        |> below
            [ el Menu [ alignRight, moveUp 15 ] <| -- Call el and pass the return value of row to it as its 3-rd argument.
                row None
                    [ spacingXY 30 0, paddingRight 20 ]
                    [ el None [] (text "menu 1")
                    , el None [] (text "menu 2")
                    ]
            ]
```